# Apply Blur effect to a ID3D11Texture2D

Tags: c++, directx

I have this code:

```
ID3D11Texture2D* Buffer;
SwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)&backBuffer);
```

to get a screenshot of my game, I want to blur it for my game GUI, I have no idea how to do it unfortunately

Comment: You can write your own shader, or you could use built-in Direct2D blur effect: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/gaussian-blur  in this case you need to create the whole Direct2D objects (device, render target, etc.) and share them: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3darticles/surface-sharing-between-windows-graphics-apis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *DirectX Tool Kit* tutorial covers writing HLSL to do blur/bloom. You may find it useful:

https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Writing-custom-shaders